# How do I get text key binding "yankAndSelect" to work?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, emacs, text-input

macOS's text input system has long supported [custom keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html) via `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`. I have used this successfully for years to make text editing more Emacs-like, but there is one feature I have never been able to get to work: the `yankAndSelect:` method.  It never cycles through the kill ring for me; it always *only* yanks the last-killed item. I am looking for help to make it work.

Here is how I tested it.  First, I set `NSTextKillRingSize` using this command in a terminal:

```
defaults write -g NSTextKillRingSize -int 20
```

(I've also tried `-string` instead of `-int` in the command above, but it makes no difference in the behavior.)  Next, I removed everything from my `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file and left only this:

```
{
  "^y" = (yankAndSelect:);
}
```

Note that I leave <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> bound to its default text system action (which is to kill to the end of the line).  Finally, I rebooted, just to be absolutely sure nothing unexpected persisted.

Based on many sources, such as [Apple's documentation](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventOverview.pdf#page=80),  the two documents on [customizing the Cocoa text system](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/site/cocoa-text.html) and [the list of selectors](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/site/selectors.html) by Jacob Rus from 2006, [Brett Terpstra's KeyBindings](https://brettterpstra.com/2015/02/05/keybindings-for-multiple-clipboards/), and random other people's pages on the web, it seems that the following behavior *should* be seen (as described by Brett Terpstra):

1. Open TextEdit (restart it if it was already open)
2. Type a line of text, move the cursor to the start of the line, type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>
3. Write another line with different text, and repeat step 2
4. Do it one more time
5. On a blank line, type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>. This should paste the last line you killed
6. Type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> again, and the pasted text should be replaced by the second line you killed
7. Again, and you should see the first line. Continuing repetitions will cycle through the kill ring.

*This is **not** what happens in my use*.  Instead, what happens is that step #6 does *not* paste the 2nd-to-last kill, but rather the most recent (3rd) kill – always.  It is as if there is no kill ring at all, and `yankAndSelect:` always only yanks the most recent kill.

This is 100% repeatable behavior in every system (macOS 10.13, and an almost-fresh 10.14 VM) and every application that respects DefaultKeyBinding.dict (not only TextEdit) that I've tried.

**What more must be done to get `yankAndSelect:` to cycle through the kill ring**?

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to work properly if you write the preference just for a single app. For instance, `defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSTextKillRingSize -string 5` causes the kill ring to work properly just in TextEdit. So it might be some sort of issue with global preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It seems that on some versions of macOS, setting the configuration globally doesn't work; instead, use `defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSTextKillRingSize -string 6` (replacing `com.apple.TextEdit` with the desired application and `6` with the desired kill ring size) to set it on a per-app basis. Additionally, it appears that `NSTextKillRingSize` must be no greater than 16 or it will not work.

---

Original answer:

The issue appears to lie in how the `defaults` CLI handles the global defaults domain. Specifically, you want to write to the correct *host*'s global defaults (i.e., yours), which it seems doesn't occur by default. (I still don't fully understand the intricacies of how all this works.) To accomplish this, replace your current `defaults write` command with the following:

```
defaults -currentHost write -g NSTextKillRingSize -string 6
```

This worked for me on Big Sur 11.1.

Comment: I appreciate this effort. The command does not seem to work for me (on 10.13.6), nor the other variant using the specific app code, but I want to do more testing with another computer, clean environment, rebooting, etc. It's hopeful to have confirmation that it still _does_ work for recent OSes, at least for other people!

Comment: @mhucka One thing I've noticed is its "cycling" behavior is somewhat erratic—if you press control+y multiple times *consecutively* (i.e., without pressing return/deselecting the text) with several items in the kill ring, does it cycle through them then?

Comment: No; in fact, pressing it consecutively is actually what I've been doing all along. (Leaving the selected text selected is what I assumed one had to do in order to get it replaced with the previous yank.)

Comment: SOLVED. You're not going to believe this. If you use a value greater than 16, it does not work; **if you use 16 or less, it works**. In addition, I have to use the version in your earlier comment (`defaults write com.apple.TextEdit ...` rather than `defaults -currentHost write`), but with that combination, it worked everywhere I tried it on 10.13 and 10.14. If you could update this answer to say something about the single app vs. `-currentHost`, I'll be happy to award the bonus.

Comment: P.S. if you open your window, you may hear the sound of my screaming.

Comment: Aha! I actually originally used `6` in my answer and then changed it to `20` to match yours…whoops! I'll update my answer.

Comment: I can't believe what an obscure implementation detail we seem to have stumbled upon. I used 20 kind of arbitrarily because most examples had, e.g., 5, and I wanted more. 100 seemed too much, 10 was on the edge of useful vs not useful, so 20. Who could have guessed there was an undocumented limitation like this?